# List добавить в базу данных для сохранения в excel

Tags: python, парсер, youtube

Парсил ресурс. Появился вопрос. Как добавить список(cards) в моем случае в базу данных, для сохранения в excel. Код то рабочий. Но вот мой список cards приходиться копировать из консоли и потом ручками добавлять в бд. Прописывать, etc. Не true. *Надо чтобы автоматом подхватывал мой cards лист и вставлял в pd.DataFrame(cards).transpose().* И вообще, как оптимизировать мой код. Один раз такое вылезло - резы из паралльельных кодов, какие то левые данные оказались в консоли. И потом total резалт в excel не так настроен - вместо столбцов - строки.

`````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/'
HOST = 'https://wordpress.org'
HEADERS = {
    'accept': '.....,
    'user-agent': '......'
}


def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r.text


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    popular = soup.find_all('section')[1]  # обращаемся ко второму элементу списка
    plugins = popular.find_all('article')

    # return (str(plugins).ljust(5))

    # cards = []
    # print(items)
    # 1,560
    def refined(s):
        r = s.split(' ')[0]  # сплит по пробелу, забираем первый элемент
        return r.replace(',', '')
        # print(result)

    cards = []

    for plugin in plugins:
        r = plugin.find('span', class_='rating-count').find('a').get_text()
        cards.append({

            'name': plugin.find('h3').text,
            'url': plugin.find('h3').find('a').get('href'),
            'rating': refined(r)  # функци refined удаляет пробелы и запятые, применительно к функции r
        # print(rating)
        # 'link_product': HOST + item.find('div', class_='title').find('a').get('href')
        # 'brand': item.find('div', class_='title').get_text(strip=True),
        # 'card_img': HOST + item.find('div', class_='image').find('img').get('src')
        })
    return cards
# html = get_html(URL)
# print(get_content(html.text))
cards = [{'name': 'Classic Editor', 'url': 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/', 'rating': '903'}, {'name': 'Akismet Spam Protection', 'url': 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/akismet/', 'rating': '909'}, {'name': 'Jetpack – WP Security, Backup, Speed, & Growth', 'url': 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/', 'rating': '1560'}, {'name': 'bbPress', 'url': 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/bbpress/', 'rating': '315'}]
print(type(cards))
df = pd.DataFrame(cards).transpose()
# df = pd.DataFrame(lst).transpose()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Wordpress.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 80, format1)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 35, format1)
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B8', {'type': '3_color_scale'})
writer.save()

def main():
    url = 'https://wordpress.org/plugins'
    print(get_content(get_html(url)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

````
`````

Comment: Очевидно, `get_text` применимо только к объектам `BeautifulSoup`, а вы пытаетесь применить его к строке.

Comment: Решил вопрос. Появился новый. Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Все решается просто. Убрать строчку с transpose - не разобрался, предварительно с документацией Pandas проблема swap strokes to colums. Переместить блок с df = pd.DataFrame выше. Прямо к циклу. Так или иначе все срастается. Вот другой парсер, все пашет:

`````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://mastermoz.com/entertainment/movies/{}/'
HEADERS = {
    'accept': '...',
    'user-agent': '...'
}


def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r.text


def get_content(html, df_transposed=None):      #get_page_data
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='card-img-overlay-bottom z-index-20')
 
    cards = []
 

    for item in items:
        cards.append({
            'name': item.find('h4', class_='text-white text-shadow').text,
            'url': item.find('a', class_='title-link').get('href'),



        })
    # print(len(items))
    df = pd.DataFrame(cards)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('study1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
    format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
    worksheet.set_column('B:B', 80, format1)
    worksheet.set_column('C:C', 35, format1)
    worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B8', {'type': '3_color_scale'})
    writer.save()
def main():
    pattern = 'https://mastermoz.com/entertainment/movies/{}/'


    for i in range(1, 5):
        url = pattern.format(str(i))
        # print(url)
        get_content(get_html(url))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

````
`````